# Regular expression, matching "UnQualified" strings

Tags: regex

Test data

```
1: "Abc.TestCase For TestCase By Abc.TestCase Using TestCase"           --> 2 matches 
2: "(Abc.TestCase For TestCase By Abc.TestCase Using TestCase)"         --> 2 matches
3: "(TestCase For TestCase By Abc.TestCase Using TestCase)"             --> 3 matches
4: "(Abc.TestCase For TestCase By Abc.TestCase Using Xyz.TestCase.Sub)" --> 1 match
5: "(Abc.TestCase For TestCase By Abc.TestCase Using Xyz.TestCase1)"    --> 1 match
```

Target is to obtain the **unqualified** "TestCase"

have tried the following

```
[^.]\bTestCase\b[^.]
```

while this works it fails with 2 & 3 case where it returns "(TestCase" "TestCase)" as matches, which would then lead erroneous results in the replacement.

at a wit's end for this !

would appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
(?<!\.)\bTestCase\b(?!\.)
```

In other words, you want to match the whole word `TestCase` (i.e., not preceded or followed another word character), but not if it's immediately preceded or followed by `.`.  Here's a slightly neater version:

```
(?<!\.\w)TestCase(?!\.\w)
```

The way you wrote the question, it sounds like you also want to exclude matches that are preceded or followed by parentheses, like `(TestCase` or `TestCase)`, but I finally realized you just don't want to include the parens in the match.  Replacing the negated character classes (`[^.]`) with negative lookarounds ( `(?<!\.)` and `(?!\.])` ) meets that requirement because lookarounds don't consume what they match.

Comment: thank you alan, first one works like charm, as well mentioning the lookaround. Apologies for the question not being clear enough in the intent

Answer (score 1):

Your are close

The problem is that ) and " are considered word boundaries

So if you add the exceptions to the character class like so

```
[^.]\bTestCase\b[^").]
```

your regex will match only the first occurrence of TestCase

**Update 1**

[image]

BTW, looking at your sample input I think " TestCase " as a regex would work as well. But maybe you have more edge cases

Comment: exactly i need to ignore the characters "(" & ")" was not aware they are considered word boundaries, have edited the question to indicate this

Comment: Just add them to the character class. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: well that would that then match "(TestCase" & "TestCase)" which would be then would lead errorneous replacement results. Apologies for the question not being clear enough on that aspect

Comment: @kalki Updated my answer to show that it matches what you require

Comment: the kicker is the case 3 where "TestCase" succeeding "(" and "TestCase" preceeding ")", i need them to return as matches but only "TestCase" else replacement goes haywire i.e. can not loose the brackets during replacement. Is it possible to say mention the boundaries explicitly i.e. starting with "T" and ending with "e"

Comment: Hmz, I don't understand anymore what's needed. Can you update your answer with some sample input where you make the matches you want bold? I though you only wanted 1 match for line 3. Comments on SO are not good to put formatting.

Comment: thank you for the time & effort buckley, should have been more clear with the question have edited to reflect it so